# Pandas Remove Blank Row in Column Multi Index

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, multi-index

I have a `MultiIndex` dataframe in pandas.  I can't seem to get rid of the blank row under the column headers in the resulting Excel file while maintaining the multi-indices.

Here is what I have:

|  |  |  |  | 3 Month Total | 3 Month Total | 3 Month Total | August | August | August | July | July | July | June | June | June |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | variable | Sales | Cost | GP | Sales | Cost | GP | Sales | Cost | GP | Sales | Cost | GP |
| Division | Region | Store | Employee |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Commerical | Texas | 0001 | Bob | 1000 | 600 | 400 | 450 | 200 | 250 | 150 | 100 | 50 | 400 | 300 | 100 |
| Retail | West | 0406 | Sally | 2400 | 1700 | 700 | 1100 | 800 | 300 | 750 | 500 | 250 | 550 | 400 | 150 |

Here is what I want:

|  |  |  |  | 3 Month Total | 3 Month Total | 3 Month Total | August | August | August | July | July | July | June | June | June |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Division | Region | Store | Employee | Sales | Cost | GP | Sales | Cost | GP | Sales | Cost | GP | Sales | Cost | GP |
| Commerical | Texas | 0001 | Bob | 1000 | 600 | 400 | 450 | 200 | 250 | 150 | 100 | 50 | 400 | 300 | 100 |
| Retail | West | 0406 | Sally | 2400 | 1700 | 700 | 1100 | 800 | 300 | 750 | 500 | 250 | 550 | 400 | 150 |

Can someone please point me in the right direction ?

I [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76078773/remove-blank-line-when-displaying-multiindex-python-dataframe) but hard coding values won't work for me as the columns headers change.

Edit: here is the df.head().to_dict('tight') as requested.

```
{'index': [('Commerical',
   'Service',
   426,
   'Los Angeles, CA',
   2767,
   78910,
   'Steve'),
  ('Retail', 'Service', 1, 'Houston, TX', 2706, 123456, 'Bob')],
 'columns': [('3 Months Combined', 'Adjusted Hrs'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Clocked Hrs'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'GP'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'GP-Supp'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Mobile'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Prd Hrs'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Sum of Days Worked'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Supp $'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Total Billed Hrs'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Total Billed Revenue'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Total Clocked Hrs'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Total External Cost'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Total Non Billed Hrs'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Rev/Day'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Hrs Billed/Day'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Prof%'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'GP/Day'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'GP-Supp/Day'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Avg Supp/Day'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Eff Rate'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Prod%'),
  ('3 Months Combined', 'Eff%'),
  ('August', 'Title'),
  ('August', 'Level'),
  ('August', '40-30-20-10'),
  ('August', 'Rev/Day'),
  ('August', 'Hrs Billed/Day'),
  ('August', 'Prof%'),
  ('August', 'GP/Day'),
  ('August', 'GP-Supp/Day'),
  ('August', 'GP%'),
  ('August', 'Total Supp $/Day'),
  ('August', 'Eff Rate'),
  ('August', 'Prod%'),
  ('August', 'Eff%'),
  ('August', 'Labor Rate'),
  ('August', 'Tech Count'),
  ('July', 'Title'),
  ('July', 'Level'),
  ('July', '40-30-20-10'),
  ('July', 'Rev/Day'),
  ('July', 'Hrs Billed/Day'),
  ('July', 'Prof%'),
  ('July', 'GP/Day'),
  ('July', 'GP-Supp/Day'),
  ('July', 'GP%'),
  ('July', 'Total Supp $/Day'),
  ('July', 'Eff Rate'),
  ('July', 'Prod%'),
  ('July', 'Eff%'),
  ('July', 'Labor Rate'),
  ('July', 'Tech Count'),
  ('June', 'Title'),
  ('June', 'Level'),
  ('June', '40-30-20-10'),
  ('June', 'Rev/Day'),
  ('June', 'Hrs Billed/Day'),
  ('June', 'Prof%'),
  ('June', 'GP/Day'),
  ('June', 'GP-Supp/Day'),
  ('June', 'GP%'),
  ('June', 'Total Supp $/Day'),
  ('June', 'Eff Rate'),
  ('June', 'Prod%'),
  ('June', 'Eff%'),
  ('June', 'Labor Rate'),
  ('June', 'Tech Count')],
 'data': [[-81.30000000000001,
   501.06,
   32378.5,
   31716.28,
   0,
   473.83,
   60,
   662.22,
   497.8,
   48308.100000000006,
   579.3,
   15929.6,
   2.5,
   805.1350000000001,
   8.296666666666667,
   0.8556204881402545,
   539.6416666666667,
   528.6046666666666,
   11.037,
   97.0431900361591,
   0.9409603622209866,
   0.8284194753392566,
   'VEH MOD TECH 4',
   4,
   0.863313125913714,
   422.890476190476,
   5.03809523809524,
   1.01584253480557,
   261.671428571429,
   261.671428571429,
   0.618768790748477,
   0.0,
   83.9385633270321,
   0.954909470752089,
   1.02035855363112,
   32,
   1,
   'VEH MOD TECH 4',
   4,
   1.9189405558250532,
   1547.32470588235,
   15.2764705882353,
   0.829235583370586,
   1058.47764705882,
   1019.52352941176,
   0.684069505925217,
   38.9541176470588,
   101.288101655757,
   0.976361031518625,
   0.625972120322817,
   32,
   1,
   'VEH MOD TECH',
   4,
   0.9339213695893974,
   596.494545454546,
   6.01363636363636,
   0.804402018605217,
   404.058181818182,
   404.058181818182,
   0.677387890463069,
   0.0,
   99.1903250188964,
   0.902629931120852,
   0.805353220025436,
   32,
   1],
  [18.8,
   462.45,
   27412.2,
   27214.64,
   'XXX',
   462.45,
   32,
   197.56,
   476.01,
   45859.7,
   470.95,
   18447.5,
   1.0,
   1433.115625,
   14.8753125,
   1.0086026062082847,
   856.63125,
   850.4575,
   6.17375,
   96.3418835738745,
   0.9978422699320315,
   1.040653043572278,
   'MBL SVC TECH 5',
   5,
   1.0367635962028665,
   758.888888888889,
   9.61111111111111,
   1.02366863905325,
   278.333333333333,
   256.382222222222,
   0.366764275256223,
   21.9511111111111,
   78.9595375722543,
   0.992994746059545,
   1.0,
   50,
   1,
   'MBL SVC TECH 5',
   5,
   1.5748790164805966,
   1449.45,
   16.0227272727273,
   1.0,
   1149.45,
   1149.45,
   0.79302494049467,
   0.0,
   90.4621276595745,
   1.0,
   1.0,
   50,
   1,
   'MBL SVC TECH 5',
   5,
   1.8559248654501908,
   1923.8125,
   17.7716666666667,
   1.00975378787879,
   1021.9375,
   1021.9375,
   0.531204314349761,
   0.0,
   108.251664634718,
   1.0,
   1.1544782251438,
   50,
   1]],
 'index_names': ['Division',
  'Department',
  'Profit Center',
  'Branch',
  'Tech ID',
  'Employee No',
  'Tech Name'],
 'column_names': [None, 'variable']}
```

Edit 2: I am reading several data files into data frames, merging them, and do a melt so I can do some calculations and group by month.  I then take the dataframe and put it in a pivot table so everything is grouped by month. This new pivot table is df1. I do another pivot table, from the original data frame, where it is the 3 month combined totals, called df2.  I then merge these two pivot tables to create a new pivot table, df3, which is what you see here.

Comment: Can you provide your dataframe as code `df.head().to_dict()`? Are you reading from a csv?

Comment: Or rather `df.head().to_dict('tight')` to have all infos ;)

Comment: It is not totally clear from this post exactly what your input dataframe structure is.   Hence using to_dict and show this in this post will help others help you.

Comment: @not_speshal, I am reading from a file

Comment: @not_speshal, sample info is now up

Comment: @mozway, sample info is now up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect such output *for visual purposes*, you can try something like below :

```
def shift_header(df, cols):
    return df.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True).set_axis(cols, axis=1)

l0, l1 = zip(*df.columns)

left = df.index.to_frame(index=False).pipe(shift_header, cols=[""]*len(df.index.names))
right = (
    pd.DataFrame(df.reset_index(drop=True).to_numpy(), columns=l1)
        .pipe(shift_header, cols=l0)
)
  
out = pd.concat([left, right], axis=1)
```

Output :

|  |  |  |  |  | 3 Month Total | 3 Month Total | 3 Month Total | August | August | August | July | July | July | June | June | June |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Division | Region | Store | Employee | Sales | Cost | GP | Sales | Cost | GP | Sales | Cost | GP | Sales | Cost | GP |
| 1 | Commerical | Texas | 1 | Bob | 1000 | 600 | 400 | 450 | 200 | 250 | 150 | 100 | 50 | 400 | 300 | 100 |
| 2 | Retail | West | 406 | Sally | 2400 | 1700 | 700 | 1100 | 800 | 300 | 750 | 500 | 250 | 550 | 400 | 150 |

Used input :

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=[0, 1]).rename_axis([None, "variable"], axis=1)
```

***UPDATE*** :

If you need to make an *Excel spreadsheet*, you can use :

```
df = df.rename_axis([None]*df.columns.nlevels, axis=1)

CORNER = len(df.index.names)
        
borders = {"border": "1px solid black"}
fill_data = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy()).style.set_properties(**borders)

with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer: 
    df.reset_index(drop=True).to_excel(writer, startcol=CORNER-1) # bottom part
    df.index.to_frame().iloc[:, 0:0].to_excel(writer, startrow=0) # left part
    fill_data.to_excel(writer, startrow=2, startcol=CORNER, header=False, index=False)
    writer.sheets["Sheet1"].delete_rows(len(df)+3) # clean up
```

Output (*output.xlsx*) :

[image]

Comment: This is awesome!  Thank you!
Is it possible to keep the grouped indices (e.g. everything under "August" has one merged cell above it titled 'August'?)

Do you recommend a better approach to the how I structured everything?

Comment: You're welcome. I suppose that you need to write the output to an Excel spreadsheet. Is it the case ?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I added an update to address this. Can you check it out ?

Comment: This is wonderful!  You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

The reason, why your dataframe is rendered that way, is that both your row index and your column index are multi-indices with **named** index dimensions.

E.g. "variable" is the name of the second dimension of your column index, "Divison", "Region", "Store", "Employee" are the names of the dimensions of your row index.

Since the names of the row index dimensions are distinct from the values of the second dimension of your column index, they are not rendered in the same row in the output.

Here is a short example to illustrate the different elements:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
  [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
  index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("R1", "r1"), ("R2", "r2")], names=["row_index_name_1", "row_index_name_2"]),
  columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("A", "a"), ("B", "b")], names=["col_index_name_1", "col_index_name_2"])
)
```

|  | col_index_name_1 | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | col_index_name_2 | a | b |
| row_index_name_1 | row_index_name_2 |  |  |
| R1 | r1 | 1 | 2 |
| R2 | r2 | 3 | 4 |

One solution to remove the empty row is to convert your row indices to normal columns:

```
df.reset_index()
```

| col_index_name_1 | row_index_name_1 | row_index_name_2 | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| col_index_name_2 |  |  | a | b |
| 0 | R1 | r1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | R2 | r2 | 3 | 4 |

Comment: Do you recommend a better approach to the how I structure this from the get go?

Comment: This depends on where the multi-indices originate from and if they are really needed. If they are not needed, I would just convert the row indices to columns. I edited my answer to suggest this.